# Symmetric sigmoidal function with asymptotes?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, symmetric-functions

Consider the cubic function:

f(x) = x + ax^3

[Simple cubic function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlp9Q.png)

This function has several of the features that I need, which are:

1. crosses the origin (0,0)
2. If x > 0 then y <= x
3. If x < 0 then y >= x
4. Symmetric: f(x) = -f(-x)
5. parameter "a" regulates the departure from the y=x line

HOWEVER, instead of "bending up/downwards" like the cubic function, in addition to all properties listed above, I would like a horizontal asymptotic function that gradually curves and "levels off" towards a parameter value. So, the function should have just one root (0,0).

It feels like a function from the family of sigmoid curves could do the trick, but after trying for many days I still have not found the right equation.

Comment: Maybe something like $y=\frac{2a}{\pi}\arctan x$? It has asymptotes $y=a$ at $+\infty$ and $y=-a$ at $-\infty$.

Comment: Thanks GReyes for the suggestion. Indeed the function asymptotes towards +/- a, which is what I was looking for. However, conditions 2 and 3 are not met at larger values of parameter "a" (i.e. y must be <= x). Any more ideas?

Comment: Check out $y = a*tanh(x/a)$ or $y = ax/sqrt(x^2+a^2)$.

Comment: Thanks @M.Wind, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: There is also $y = b*\arctan(x/b)$ where $b=(2/\pi)a$. All three formulas are sigmoidal and satisfy your conditions. All three have asymptotes $+a$ and $-a$ as asymptotes. So you can also choose a linear combination of the three functions. Have fun !

Comment: I see your point, @M.Wind. The difference between the three curves is their rate of increase: tanh() is the fastest, followed by the sqrt(), and then by the arctan().

Comment: @M.Wind, would you know how I could modify any of them, say the sqrt(), to control the rate of increase. For example, assume that, with an additional parameter 0 < k < 1 the curve may go from a low rate to a high rate. In that case, if k = 1 then the curve would become a strait diagonal line until it reaches the asymptote a, which then flattens out. Ideas?

Comment: Sure, you may consider the function $y=ax/(abs(x)^k+a^k)^{(1/k)}$. For $k=2$
 you have a smooth transition. Choose a higher value for $k$, and the transition between linear regime and asymptote becomes more abrupt.

Comment: Thanks again @M.Wind, brilliant! Exactly what I was looking for! Best